# quering mysql via command line shows column values as?

Tags: mysql, command-line, utf-8, latin

My `table` `Collation` is `Latin` but the `columns` are `utf8 unicode`... and i can store text in any language without any problems

however, when i go into `console` to check out some stuff i see the `non-latin` text as `?????` but on the website they appear fine...

```
| 30 | 8196371 | 5842337911 | ???????????? | ?????? ??? ??? ???????????
```

is this is a problem or its just how the console works?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start your console with this option: “–default-character-set=utf8″